# How do I extract the last element of the list in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have the following in a variable in Perl.

```
my $test = *             file/test/ttt/rrr/aaa/abc.fff.ter.yyy:myfilename.txt
```

I want to extract

```
myfilename.txt
```

The initial path with / will change (there may be many directories which are not fixed), and I only want the last file name.

How can I do this?

I tried to use:

```
$filename= (split /\//, $test)[4] ;
```

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is probably to use a module designed for this exact thing.

```
use File::Basename;
my $filename = basename($test);
```

Other solutions are likely regex based:

If you want to extract the part of a string that is after a colon, like in this string, you could do:

```
my ($filename) = $test =~ /:(.+)/;
```

Or if you want to extract a basename + extension at the end

```
my ($filename) = $test =~ /(\w+\.\w+)$/;
```

Or a `split` based solution

```
my $filename = (split /:/, $test)[-1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can count backward from the end of a list with a negative index. The last element of a list is `-1`, the next to last `-2`, and so on:

```
$filename= (split /\//, $test)[-1];
```

If you have your list in an array, the `$#array_name` is the index of the last element. That's a bit more clunky than just using `-1` though:

```
my @array = qw( 1 3 7 );
my $last = $array[$#array];
```

If you don't care about the array, you can remove the last element with `pop`, which returns that value:

```
my $last = pop @array
```

Answer (score -1):

Added one of the methods from the above answers:

```
$fullpath = $ARGV[0];

my ($filename) = $fullpath=~m/(?:\\|\/)(?:[^\:]+)\:([^\/\\]+)$/;

print $filename;
```

The above code should work Windows or Linux.